# Vue 3 - Uncaught TypeError: Vue is not a constructor

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to do a simple js method with Vue 3 but in the console appears `Uncaught TypeError: Vue is not a constructor`.

This vue project is installed inside a laravel project, hence the structure. I tried exactly the same with the same code in Vue 2 and it's working.

After many tests I know the main problem is that piece of code in the `form.js` with the `new Vue({})` syntax.

I searched but there's no any answer for this syntax in particulary.

Any idea how I should write it in Vue 3?

`form.js`

```
new Vue({
    el: '#form',

    methods: {
        clickme: function () {
            alert('Hello World');
            console.log('Its working');
        },
    },
});
```

`app.js`

```
import './bootstrap';

import Alpine from 'alpinejs';

window.Alpine = Alpine;

Alpine.start();

window.Vue = require('vue').default;

if ($('#form').length > 0) {
    require('./form.js');
} else {
    const app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
    });
}
```

`form.blade.php`

```
<div id="form">
    <button @click="clickme()">Click me</button>
</div>

<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: The first page of the official guide shows the correct usage, https://vuejs.org/guide/introduction.html . There's no `new Vue` in Vue 3

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, I solved it:

`form.js`

```
// Element added manually due to new Vue 3 structure
import { createApp } from 'vue';
//

// New "createApp" structure to substitute Vue 2 "const app = new Vue" code
let form = createApp({
    el: '#form',

    methods: {
        clickme: function () {
            alert('Hello World');
            console.log('Its working');
        },
    }, 
})

form.mount("#form");
//
```

`app.js`

```
import './bootstrap';

import Alpine from 'alpinejs';

// Element added manually due to new Vue 3 structure
import { createApp } from 'vue';
//

window.Alpine = Alpine;

Alpine.start();

window.Vue = require('vue').default;

if ($('#form').length > 0) {
    require('./form.js');
} else {
    // New "createApp" structure to substitute Vue 2 "const app = new Vue" code
    let app = createApp({
        el: '#app',
    });

    app.mount("#app");
    //
}
```